# ¿ cuando ejecuto ./manage.py makemigration ? marca el error ImportError: No module adopcion.models

Tags: django

tengo:
python 2.7.9
django 1.11.6
psycopg2=2.5.4
postgres 9.4
linux debian 8.4x64

sigo el ejemplo de django de código facilito y a la hora de ejecutar la relación que esta en https://codigofacilito.com/videos/6-curso-django-relaciones 7:08 marca el error indicado ImportError: No module named adopcion.models les anexo todo el código en un zip. https://filenurse.com/download/dcb455d3247b88f40787a2cbf94eb187.html (7 días si desean que lo vuelva a subir solo comentarlo)

Comment: Por qué mejor no escribes el código acá, para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: StackOverflow te permite colocar código en la pregunta, no hay restricción temporal ni nada similar, para que tu pregunta sea mejor aceptada, te invito a que pongas el código aquí, y utilices los corchetes para marcarlo como código en la pregunta, saludos :)